# Does the Disney canon of Star Wars include any multiple-biome planets?

Tags: star-wars, planets, trope

Star Wars is quite famous for fitting the [Single Biome Planet](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet) trope to a T (warning: TVTropes link). You have the desert worlds of Tatooine and Jakku, the Forest Moon of Endor, the woodland planet of Kashyyyk, the volcanic planet of Mustafar, the ice worlds of Hoth and Ilum, the cloud-world of Bespin, the mud-drenched Mimban, the all-one-city urban Coruscant, Exegol where lightning rages all hours of the day, etc.

Within the Disney canon of Star Wars, are there any planets that are specifically known to not be single-biome? The closest I can think of is Naboo with its underground domed cities *and* more traditional above-ground cities, but there doesn't seem to be any indication that the *climate* is truly different in different areas, it's more of an "oh, we also built cities at the bottom of the sea because plot" thing. Ordinary seas and islands don't count unless there is a *trope-breaking* difference (that is, this question is about trope-breaking, not about biomes as they are formally defined in geology). Are there any planets that are either shown *on-screen* as having multiple biomes (e.g. desert and jungle; glacier and rain forest; grasslands, fungal forest, and tundra; etc.), or that can be shown to be multiple biome according to *canon* Disney works?

A canon reference could be something as simple as, "He set down his X-Wing in the tiny area near Tatooine's north pole where trees grew in abundance."

Comment: Minban also has swamplands as well as mud fields. Does that count?

Comment: @Valorum if the swamplands are shown or described in a canon (non-Legends) source, then yes.

Comment: **Soldier 1:** "*To the southern marshlands! Move out!"* (Solo: A Star Wars Story)

Comment: We only see small little pieces of any planet other than Tatooine. Most of the others could be extreme multi-biome and we just don't know it.

Comment: What about [Alderaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alderaan#Description)? (Or is the source non-canon?)

Comment: Assuming the Endor shown in RoS is the same Endor from RotJ - it has both a forest and an ocean

Comment: Also, doesn't *Solo* feature mountain and oceanside scenes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**[Ryloth](https://www.starwars.com/databank/ryloth)** seems a pretty good fit. It has a wide range of 'biomes' seen in the canon Clone Wars series including some rugged mountain areas seemingly devoid of life as well as jungles.

> **TERRAIN:** Jungles,  Mesas, Valleys,  Volcanoes
>
> <sub>[Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/ryloth)</sub>

[image: Person against a tree in the jungle]

[image: craters in a barren dusty brown area]

[image: view of planet from space, showing different terrains]

---

You might also consider [Jaresh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jaresh). It appears in the (canon) book [*Moving Target: A Princess Leia Adventure*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Moving_Target:_A_Princess_Leia_Adventure).

> We’re at war, Cracken had said, and Leia had accepted that. But now she wondered how much evil had been done, deliberately or not, because of that excuse.
> **Below the Mellcrawler hung the planet Jaresh, like a green jewel in space. As the yacht approached, Leia could see thin blue lines carved across the continents, marking a complex series of irrigation canals that brought water from enormous polar ice caps to the more temperate regions.**

Comment: I don't know...that's like one stand of trees surrounded by dry mesas. Though there is a big green splotch visible from space.

Comment: Is it just me who read "Terrain: Mesas" and heard it in a Jar Jar Binks voice?

Answer (score 22):

### Naboo

I know that you disqualified Naboo already,  but I think that you failed to consider that we know that Naboo has large marshy forests (where the Jedi first met Jar Jar), and it also has large rolling plains (where the Gungans fought the droid army).

Comment: They all seem to be temperate. And within a fairly close proximity

Comment: Less a rolling plain, more like a badly-textured green carpet. But then Lucasfilm were years off the pace on CGI, back then.

Comment: @Valorum The plains are near Theed. The marshes are near Lake Paonga, which contains Otoh Gunga. Since they had to travel through the planet core to get from Otoh Gunga to Theed, I think they must be pretty distant from each other, if not on opposite sides of the planet.

Comment: @gormadoc - you've misunderstood the principle of the planet core. They didn't travel through the literal core, they went underground and traveled sidewards

Comment: @Valorum Unless they've made new material on Naboo that explanation is Legends now (where the biomes are split by the mountain range anyway); there's no description of what the planet core is and the caves have their own name now. It doesn't really matter if it's the literal core or not; for a short distance it would be better to go through the lake in the bongo and walk the rest of the way than take a convoluted path much deeper. At planetary radii and small depth the two arcs are pretty much the same, so every km down you just lose that km, even adjusting for speed and bigger fish.

Comment: @gormadoc - You see the planet core and an outline of their route in the "Inside the Worlds" factbook. It's made pretty clear that they don't drill down through the *middle* of the planet; https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM7wc.png

Comment: @Valorum Is the "Inside the Worlds" series Disney canon or is that picture from the 2016 factbook? I do agree that it was the case previously, but AFAIK there's nothing Disney canon about it now. But again, it doesn't matter if they go through the middle or not, there isn't much in time-savings to go through caves underneath the surface rather than just go along waterways near the surface if they're nearby.

Comment: @gormadoc - I believe that article was also in the 2016 version, but that being said, it's highly unlikely that future canon will supersede this.

Answer (score 9):

I think Parnassoss, Phasma's homeworld. We start the book in the coastal area where the Skyre Clan leaves, we see the grassy plains where the Claw clan lives, the desert, the enclosed cities. It's a rather varied world as far as most Star Wars planets seem to be. And before the devastation we know it was similar to earth. This would include a variety of biomes around the planet. You can check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7I1sqd7Gk8) from Star Wars Explained that gives a background on the planet itself.